# How to dispatch incoming NetSocket handlers into different event loop threads?

Tags: vert.x

I'm trying to use Vertx to implement a TCP server, accepting incoming connections and then handling different sockets. Since each socket can be handled independently, the handlers belonging to different sockets are supposed to run in different event loop threads concurrently.

According to [Vert.x document](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_standard_verticles),

> Standard verticles are assigned an event loop thread when they are created and the start method is called with that event loop. When you call any other methods that takes a handler on a core API from an event loop then Vert.x will guarantee that those handlers, when called, will be executed on the same event loop.

I think, this code snippet can print different thread names:

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(); // The number of event loop threads is 2*core.
vertx.createNetServer().connectHandler(socket -> {
    vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {
        @Override
        public void start() throws Exception {
            socket.handler(buffer -> {
                log.trace(socket.toString() + ": Socket Message");
                socket.close();
            });
        }
    });
}).listen(port);
```

But unfortunately, all handlers were located in the same thread.

```
23:59:42.359 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] TRACE Server - io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl@253fa4f2: Socket Message
23:59:42.364 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] TRACE Server - io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl@465f1533: Socket Message
23:59:42.365 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] TRACE Server - io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl@5ab8dac: Socket Message
23:59:42.366 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] TRACE Server - io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl@5fc72993: Socket Message
23:59:42.367 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] TRACE Server - io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl@38ee66d7: Socket Message
23:59:42.368 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] TRACE Server - io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl@6a60a74: Socket Message
23:59:42.369 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] TRACE Server - io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl@5f3921e1: Socket Message
23:59:42.370 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] TRACE Server - io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl@39d41024: Socket Message
... more than 100+ lines ...
```

An opposite example is similar to [this echo server written in BOOST.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/spawn/echo_server.cpp). The handlers run in different event loop threads if a thread pool is used to execute `io_service::run()`.

So, my question is how to run these handlers concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do something entirely different from what you intend.

Each time you receive connection on your socket, you launch a new actor,

Simplest way to prove that:

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(); // The number of event loop threads is 2*core.
vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(request -> {

    vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {

        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); // Some random unique number

        @Override
        public void start() throws Exception {
            request.response().end(uuid + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

    });
}).listen(8888);



vertx.setPeriodic(1000, r -> {
   System.out.println(vertx.deploymentIDs().size()); // Print verticles count every second
});
```

I'm using httpServer just because it's easier to check in browser.
As wrong as it may be, you'll still see that you should receive different threads:

```
fe931b18-89cc-4c6a-9d6a-8565bb1f1c12 vert.x-eventloop-thread-9
277330da-4df8-4e91-bd8f-82c0f62156d0 vert.x-eventloop-thread-11
bbd3207c-80a4-41d8-9be5-b40727badc84 vert.x-eventloop-thread-13
```

Now to how you should do it:

```
// We create 10 workers
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {

        @Override
        public void start() {

            vertx.eventBus().consumer("processMessage", (request) -> {
                // Do something smart

                // Reply
                request.reply("I'm on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            });
        }
    });
}

// This is your handler
vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(request -> {
    // Only one server, that should dispatch events to workers as quickly as possible
    vertx.eventBus().send("processMessage", null, (response) -> {
        if (response.succeeded()) {
            request.response().end("Request :" + response.result().body().toString());
        }
        // Handle errors
    });
}).listen(8888);

vertx.setPeriodic(1000, r -> {
    System.out.println(vertx.deploymentIDs().size()); // Notice that number of workers doesn't change
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand yet. The difference between your code and mine is the location to deploy worker verticles. You deploy them outside, while I deploy them in a handler. Does it mean that verticles deployed in some handler would inherit the thread of deploying handler? And what is it really intended if yes?

Comment: You're creating verticles for each request. You shouldn't do that. Verticles don't inherit thread. If you run my example you'll see that although I'm creating verticles same way as you do, I'm getting different threads each time. The reason you think you're on the same thread is probably how you deal with your Net client. But that's another subject.

Comment: Why shouldn't do that? What's the difference? I can't find it in vert.x documents or maybe I have to read its implementation. :)

Comment: Because you introduce a memory leak that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to determine which event loop Vert.x will assign to each of your verticles without more details (number of cores of your test machines for example).

Anyway, it is not a good idea to deploy a verticle per incoming connection. Verticles are units of deployment in Vert.x. You would typically create one per "functionality".

Back to your use case, the purpose of event driven programming is precisely to avoid using a thread per connection. You can handle **a lot** of concurrent connections with a single event loop. If you have multiple cores on your machine then you can deploy multiple instances of your verticle to use them all (1 event loop per core).

```
int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
vertx.deployVerticle(TCPServerVerticle.class.getName(), new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(processors));

public class TCPServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
    vertx.createNetServer().connectHandler(socket -> {
      socket.handler(buffer -> {
        log.trace(socket.toString() + ": Socket Message");
        socket.close();
      });
    }).listen(port, ar -> {
      if (ar.succeeded()) {
        startFuture.complete();
      } else {
        startFuture.fail(ar.cause());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

With [Vertx TCP server sharing](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_scaling_sharing_tcp_servers) the connect handlers will be called on a round-robin fashion.