# Vertx Instantiating Multiple Vertical Instances listening to Same Socket

Tags: java, sockets, udp, rx-java, vert.x

I am  developing datagram server which listens to messages on a particular port and we are using Vertx Java Framework for implementing the same . Everything works fine if I specify only one instance in the Deployment Options while starting the vertical. As soon as I specify more than one instance I am getting  socket bind error. I  understand on a machine once a socket is opened and if we try to listen again on same socket it results in this error. But to take advantage of multi core processors I need to share the Datagram Socket between multiple instances of the same vertical. I am not sure how to achieve this using vertx framework . Below I have mentioned the Code snippet where I am trying to achieve the same. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
public class TestServer  extends AbstractVerticle {

@Override
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {


    DatagramSocket accessSocket = vertx.createDatagramSocket(new DatagramSocketOptions());
    int accessPort=1234;

    accessSocket.listen(accessPort, "0.0.0.0", asyncResult -> {
      if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
          accessSocket.handler(packet -> {
                logger.error("Received on  Port  "+packet);
                InetSocketAddress localAddress =  new InetSocketAddress(accessSocket.localAddress().host(), accessSocket.localAddress().port());
                InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(packet.sender().host(), packet.sender().port());
                Buffer data = packet.data();
                try {

                    //handlePacket(localAddress, remoteAddress, decodePacket);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                     System.out.println("listen Error while processing the packet " +packet,  e);
                }
        });
      } else {
        System.out.println(" listen startAccessServer Failed " + asyncResult.cause());
      }
    });
}

/*
@Override
  public void start(Future<Void> fut) {
    vertx
        .createHttpServer()
        .requestHandler(r -> {
          r.response().end("<h1>Hello from Vertx " +
              "</h1>");
        })
        .listen(8080, result -> {
          if (result.succeeded()) {
            fut.complete();
          } else {
            fut.fail(result.cause());
          }
        });
  }
  */


 public static void main(String[] args) {

    DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions();
    //options.setInstances(1);
    options.setInstances(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    Vertx.vertx().deployVerticleObservable(TestServer.class.getName(),options).subscribe();
    System.out.println("Server Started ");
 }
}
```

As soon as I run this code, this results in Socket bind exception except for the first vertical instance. If I specify options.setInstances(1) the problem gets solved but only one vertical instance gets started . I know I might be able to solve the problem using eventbus, but I don't want to head in that direction at this moment until or unless there is no other Options left out for me.

What is most interesting part here is if I comment out the first start method where I am implementing the datagram socket and uncomment the second start method where I am starting httpserver on port 8080 with the same deployment options I don't see this socket bind exception happening at all.

I belive I am missing something here in my datagram socket implementation which is resulting in this issue. Please let me know the proper way to address this issue using vertx framework.

Comment: Please check - http://stackoverflow.com/a/40205145/3940047

Comment: @PavanKumar I am asking specific to DatagramSocket for running UDP Server, the answer you mentioned talks about TCP server which I have admitted its working as  expected in my question itself .You an read more about it @ http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_scaling_sharing_tcp_servers .

Comment: There is a second part of the answer I shared where it uses eventBus - did you check that solution? I believe that should help. Scroll to the section in answer - `Now to how you should do it:`

Comment: @PavanKumar, Thanks for trying to help me, but please read my question completely. I had already specified  about Event Bus solution, In this post I am looking for something similar to HttpServer implementation where vertx instances are shared  instead of  the event bus based solution.

Comment: Sorry for missing that part. Just upvoted the issue which is shared in the answer. You too can do the same for better visibility.

Answer (score 1):

As of 3.3.3, load balancing is not supported on datagram servers. I created this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/issues/1789) to track the problem.

As a workaround, you can set the `reuseAddress` flag to rue. That will avoid the `BindException` but only one verticle instance will receive messages.

All that said, depending on your use case, a single event loop might me enough to handle your load. I'd recommend to load test it before trying workarounds using the Event Bus.

Comment: Do you see any performance issues or drawback with respect to employing a event bus based approach ?

Comment: Sending messages over the message bus is just not free. Especially in cluster mode. So if you can do with a single verticle (to be proven by load testing), keep things simple.

Comment: The load is going to be quite heavy since its going to be a smart event monitoring  system based on SNMP protocol where millions of device will be sending updates . So I need to account scalability here.  We are evaluating  vertx since its a polygot ,so we can offer our community users  to develop plugins on top of our platform for customizing our offering  I think based on your suggestion  I need to  either go through httpserver implementation and implement similar methodology myself for  load sharing using  datagram socket  or completely develop this component without using vertx.

Comment: I can only recommend to vote for the GitHub issue so that it gets included in a future version.